# Error with CreateInstanceAndUnwrap

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I just get an error each time I run this code:

```
        AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("newDomain");
        AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path);

        Command cmd = (Command)newDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assemblyName.FullName, typename);
        cmd.Execute();
```

Where `path` is the path of the Dll and `typename` is "NWT_Projekt.TestClass"

My command class:

```
using System;

namespace NWT_Projekt
{
    public interface Command
    {
        void Execute();
    }
}
```

and this is the source code of the DLL

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace NWT_Projekt
{
    public class TestClass : NWT_Projekt.Command
    {
        public MainForm f;

        public TestClass()
        {
            f = Form.ActiveForm as MainForm;
        }
        public void Execute()
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR (google translator :D)

An exception of type "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException 'occurred in NWT PRojekt.exe.

Additional information: The type "NWT_Projekt.TestClass' in Assembly 'scripts, Version = 0.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null' is not marked as serializable.

EDIT2:

With the [Serializable] it works now, but after I run the code one time and then I want to create a second dll it gives me an IO error, because the file is in use!
How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Ok, I added it to the post!

Comment: `TestClass` needs to be `[Serializable]` in order to cross appdomain boundaries. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7047153/464709).

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer, but I get a  new error :D
I updated the post!

Answer (score 1):

If you want your command to run on its own appDomain, you should use [MarshalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace NWT_Projekt
{
    public class TestClass : MarshalByRefObject, NWT_Projekt.Command
    {
        public MainForm f;

        public TestClass()
        {
            f = Form.ActiveForm as MainForm;
        }
        public void Execute()
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

I advice you to prefix your interfaces : `ICommand`